# SiteCore 6.5: Getting control parameters

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

When adding controls to a content node via the Presentation -> Layout Details -> Edit, you are allowed to add "Parameters" to the controls. How do you get those parameters from code?

I'm using the forms for web marketers and I want to pass in parameters to the form control and have access to them from custom field controls.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using

```
Sitecore.Form.Core.Renderings.FormRender frm = ((Sitecore.Form.Core.Renderings.FormRender)((Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.BaseControl)this).Form.Parent);
NameValueCollection parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(frm.Parameters);

string val = parameters["my_param"];
```

It's ugly, but it works.

Comment: yeah this is ugly but i'll try it out

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to get a parameter:

```
private string Params(string key)
{
  string rawParameters = Attributes["sc_parameters"];
  NameValueCollection parameter = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rawParameters);

  if (parameter.HasKeys())
    return parameter[key];
  return "";
 }
```

You need to add it to you sublayout .cs file and it should work.